# Javascript - How to make REST API Calls

Tags: javascript, curl, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, openwhisk

I am trying to access Firebase Database using REST API. Using cURL i am able to retrive data. I am unable to do the same in javascript.

cURL

```
curl 'https://testproject123.firebaseio.com/subscription.json?auth=aabbccddeeff123'
```

Javascript

```
var request = require('request');

var options = {
    url: 'https://testproject123.firebaseio.com/subscription.json?auth=aabbccddeeff123' };

function callback(error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        console.log(body);
    } }

request(options, callback);
```

Note: The above code i am trying to run on Bluemix/OpenWhisk.
Kindly let me know how to fix this.

Comment: What makes you think there is a problem? Are any errors reported? Your callback function takes an error argument, but the only thing you do with it is check that it is false. Have you considered actually looking at its value if it isn't false?

Comment: @Quentin
`var request = require('request');
var options = {
    url: 'https://docs-examples.firebaseio.com/rest/quickstart/users.json'
};
function callback(error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        console.log(body);
        console.log(response);
    }
    else{
    console.log(error);}}
request(options, callback);`

Comment: @Quentin
Tried the above code in jsfidlde. it does not print anything. 
But when you run 
`curl 'https://docs-examples.firebaseio.com/rest/quickstart/users.json'`
i get an output 
`{"alanisawesome":{"birthday":"June 23, 1912","name":"Alan Turing"}}`
That url is from firebase example which does not require auth.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The structure of your action is a bit off for OpenWhisk. Javascript actions need to have a `main` method and you'll have to use `whisk.async()` and `whisk.done()` to make your ([asynchronous](https://github.com/openwhisk/openwhisk/blob/master/docs/actions.md#creating-asynchronous-actions)) REST API call work as you'd expect it.

An example of how to call an external API using a Javascript action in OpenWhisk can be found [here](https://github.com/openwhisk/openwhisk/blob/master/docs/actions.md#using-actions-to-call-an-external-api).

Comment: Thank you very very much